# "TypeError: Object type <class 'str'> cannot be passed to C code" when I use Pycryptodemo and AES in Python3.8+

Tags: python

I'm a new coder and I try to use Python and Pycryptodemo to test a API and meet the Error. My code is:

```
**def base64_decode(inp):
    return base64.urlsafe_b64decode(str(inp + '=' * ((4 - len(inp) % 4) % 4)))


def base64_encode(inp):
    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(str(inp)).rstrip('=')


class AESCipher:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.BS = 16

    def pad(self, s):
        return str(s) + (self.BS - len(s) %
                    self.BS) * chr(self.BS - len(s) % self.BS)

    def unpad(self, s):
        return s[:-ord(s[len(s) - 1:])]

    def encrypt(self, raw):
        raw = self.pad(raw)
        iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
        cipher = AES.new(self.key[:16], AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return base64_encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))

    def decrypt(self, enc):
        enc = base64_decode(enc)
        iv = enc[:16]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key[:16], AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return self.unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc[16:]))


def encrypt_data(key, data):
    skey = hashlib.sha256(key.encode('utf-8')).digest()
    aes = AESCipher(skey)
    d = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False).encode("utf8")
    enc = aes.encrypt(d)
    return enc


def decrypt_data(key, s):
    skey = hashlib.sha256(key.encode('utf-8')).digest()
    aes = AESCipher(skey)
    d = aes.decrypt(s)
    data = json.loads(d)
    return data

x = {"id": "000132323kfz",
     "url": "http://robot.kangfuzi.com?a=1&b=2",
     "timestamp": int(time.time()),
     "name": u"Test"}
a = encrypt_data("user", x)
print(a)
y = decrypt_data("user", a)
print(y)
assert x == y
```

and the ERROR is:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
3      "timestamp": int(time.time()),
4      "name": u"Test"}
----> 5 a = encrypt_data("user", x)
6 print(a)
7 y = decrypt_data("user", a)

```
<ipython-input-28-12bf697a4d2e> in encrypt_data(key, data)
     36     aes = AESCipher(skey)
     37     d = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False).encode("utf8")
---> 38     enc = aes.encrypt(d)
     39     return enc
     40 

<ipython-input-28-12bf697a4d2e> in encrypt(self, raw)
     23         iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
     24         cipher = AES.new(self.key[:16], AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
---> 25         return base64_encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))
     26 
     27     def decrypt(self, enc):

E:\Alienware\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_cbc.py in encrypt(self, plaintext, output)
    176 
    177         result = raw_cbc_lib.CBC_encrypt(self._state.get(),
--> 178                                          c_uint8_ptr(plaintext),
    179                                          c_uint8_ptr(ciphertext),
    180                                          c_size_t(len(plaintext)))

E:\Alienware\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Util\_raw_api.py in c_uint8_ptr(data)
    137             return data
    138         else:
--> 139             raise TypeError("Object type %s cannot be passed to C code" % type(data))
    140 
    141     class VoidPointer_cffi(_VoidPointer):

TypeError: Object type <class 'str'> cannot be passed to C code**
```

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a dictionary.  You can only encode strings.  You can convert it to a string by using `json.dumps` BEFORE you encode it.

Of course, that means you'll have to use `json.loads` to convert it back to a dictionary after decoding.

```
x = {"id": "000132323kfz",
     "url": "http://robot.kangfuzi.com?a=1&b=2",
     "timestamp": int(time.time()),
     "name": u"Test"}
a = encrypt_data("user", json.dumps(x))
print(a)
y = json.loads(decrypt_data("user", a))
print(y)
assert x == y
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def encrypt(self, raw):
    raw = self.pad(raw)
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    raw = raw.encode()
    cipher = AES.new(self.key[:16], AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return base64_encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw)
```

It works